# context menu in QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, contextmenu, qfiledialog

I would like to implement a custom context menu in a QFileDialog. In the code below, I managed to create a context menu to the main window, but I would like the menu to be displayed when a file is selected : how to know the right widget in the QFileDialog I should apply `setContextMenuPolicy` ?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.myFileDialog = QFileDialog()

        self.myFileDialog.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.myFileDialog.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.myFileDialog)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.action_perso = QAction( "MyOwnMenu", self )
        self.connect( self.action_perso, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.test )

    def openMenu(self, position):
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction(self.action_perso)
        menu.exec_(self.myFileDialog.mapToGlobal(position))

    def test(self):
        print("coucou")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which may not be the best. It relies on two elements:

1. Thank to a personnal function `objectTree` (shown here but not used) that lists recursively all child objects of the `QFileDialog`, I identified the right widget, i.e. the `QTreeView` (I understood that the QTreeView is the right widget by trying to hide successively all QListView and QTreeView widgets). Hence, I can select it by its objectName with `self.findChild(QTreeView, "treeView"`)
2. Application of `setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.ActionsContextMenu )` to this QTreeView. I have also tried to implement a `setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)`, and it worked partially: my menu did appear but under the origin menu that was not unactivaded !
   Below is the code I propose :

---

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class CustomWidget(QFileDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        # fetch the QTreeView in the QFileDialog
        self.myTree = self.findChild(QTreeView, "treeView")

        # set the context menu policy to ActionsContextMenu
        self.myTree.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.ActionsContextMenu )

        # Define a new action
        self.action_perso = QAction( "MyOwnMenu", self.myTree )
        self.myTree.addAction( self.action_perso )

        # connect this action to a personnal function
        self.connect( self.action_perso, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.myFunction )

    def myFunction(self):
        print("coucou")

    def objectTree(self, objet, plan, j):
        """ list recursively all child objects of objet to fetch the right widget """

        n = len( objet.children() )
        for i, child in enumerate( objet.children() ):
            #print("\t"*j, end="")
            plan_sup = plan+"."+str(i)
            #print( plan_sup, child )
            if isinstance(child, QTreeView):
                self.listViews.append(child)
            self.objectTree(child, plan_sup, j+1)  


class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget,self).__init__(parent)

        #creation of main layout 
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # creation of a widget inside
        self.monWidget = CustomWidget()
        mainLayout.addWidget( self.monWidget )
        self.setLayout( mainLayout )

        self.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWidget()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```